# Rspec method is being called 2X, but can't find second time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, controller, rspec-rails

Here is my controller spec

```
before do
    @order = Order.new
end
it "should call find & assign_attributes & test delivery_start methods" do
    Order.should_receive(:find).with("1").and_return(@order)
    Order.any_instance.should_receive(:assign_attributes).with({"id"=>"1", "cancel_reason" => "random"}).and_return(@order)
    Order.any_instance.should_receive(:delivery_start).and_return(Time.now)
    post :cancel, order: {id:1, cancel_reason:"random"}
end
```

The failure is this:

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
   (#<Order:0x007fdcb03836e8>).delivery_start(any args)
       expected: 1 time with any arguments
       received: 2 times with any arguments
 # this backtrace line is ignored
```

But I'm not sure why `delivery_start` is being called twice based on this controller action:

```
def cancel
    @order = Order.find(cancel_params[:id])
    @order.assign_attributes(cancel_params)
    if (@order.delivery_start - Time.now) > 24.hours
        if refund
            @order.save
            flash[:success] = "Your order has been successfully cancelled & refunded"
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            flash[:danger] = "Sorry we could not process your cancellation, please try again"
            render nothing: true
        end
    else
        @order.save
        flash[:success] = "Your order has been successfully cancelled"
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

Comment: Sorry but it "should call find & assign_attributes & test delivery_start methods" do
    Order.should_receive(:find).with("1").and_return(@order)
    Order.any_instance.should_receive(:assign_attributes).with({"id"=>"1", "cancel_reason" => "random"}).and_return(@order)
    Order.any_instance.should_receive(:delivery_start).and_return(Time.now)
    post :cancel, order: {id:1, cancel_reason:"random"}
end

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'd be guessing that `delivery_start` might plausibly be displayed in the view that's being shown? that would be my guess at where the second "call" is coming from.

Comment: @TarynEast there is no associated view that calls `delivery_start`

Comment: It was worth checking :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you test the behavior and not the implementation. While there are cases where you would want to stub out the database doing it in a controller spec is not a great idea since you are testing the integration between your controllers and the model layer.

In addition your test is only really testing how your controller does its job - not that its actually being done.

```
describe SomeController, type: :controller do

  let(:order){ Order.create } # use let not ivars.

  describe '#cancel' do

    let(:valid_params) do
      { order: {id: '123', cancel_reason: "random"} }
    end

    context 'when refundable' do
      before { post :cancel, params }
      it 'cancels the order' do
        expect(order.reload.cancel_reason).to eq "random"
        # although you should have a model method so you can do this:
        # expect(order.cancelled?).to be_truthy
      end

      it 'redirects and notifies the user' do
         expect(response).to redirect_to root_path
         expect(flash[:success]).to eq 'Your order has been successfully cancelled & refunded'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Max, that's a fair comment, but in this case, the tests are set up that way. There are other specs that are checking that the controller's methods are working the way they are supposed to

Comment: Yeah so? Why ask if you don't want to fix it? But hey its your app.

Comment: Well... my question wasn't how to change the nature of the test, just why a specific spec may not have been passing

Comment: sometimes the best way to fix a bug... is to find a completely different, better way of doing the thing in the first place :D

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest more expectations and returning true or false depending on your use. Consider the following changes

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def cancel
    ...
    if refundable?
      ...
    end
  end

  private

  def refundable?
    (@order.delivery_start - Time.now) > 24.hours
  end
end

# spec/controllers/some_controller_spec.rb
describe SomeController, type: :controller do
  describe '#cancel' do
    context 'when refundable' do
      it 'cancels and refunds order' do
        order = double(:order)
        params = order: {id: '123', cancel_reason: "random"}
        expect(Order).to receive(:find).with('123').and_return(order)
        expect(order).to receive(:assign_attributes).with(params[:order]).and_return(order)
        expect(controller).to receive(:refundable?).and_return(true)
        expect(controller).to receive(:refund).and_return(true)
        expect(order).to receive(:save).and_return(true)
        post :cancel, params
        expect(response).to redirect_to '/your_root_path'
        expect(session[:flash]['flashes']).to eq({'success'=>'Your order has been successfully cancelled & refunded'})
        expect(assigns(:order)).to eq order
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is a very unsatisfactory answer, but I restarted my computer and the spec passed...

One thing that has been a nuisance for me before is that I've forgotten to save the code, i.e., the old version of the code the test is running against called `delivery_start` twice. But in this case, I definitely checked that I had saved. I have no idea why a restart fixed it...